Why a template<class T> parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<T>& value) method cannot be called with a std::shared_ptr<someClass> id parameter?
I'm changing a generation template of OpenAPI generator to help solving an issue affecting one user.
I'm stumbling upon what its generation causes:
A parameterToString(...) method offers many prototypes, and is used without troubles when its argument has a primitive type.
But it causes a compilation error for its templated const std::shared_ptr<T>& value or const boost::optional<const std::shared_ptr<T>>& value ones:
The method is declared in the ApiClient.h file generated:
/*
 * ApiClient.h
 * This is an API client responsible for stating the HTTP calls
 */
// [...]
class  ApiClient
{
public:
// [...]

    static utility::string_t parameterToString(utility::string_t value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(int32_t value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(int64_t value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(float value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(double value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(const utility::datetime &value);
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(bool value);
    template<class T>
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(const std::vector<T>& value);

    template<class T>
    utility::string_t parameterToString(const boost::optional<const std::shared_ptr<T>>& value);

    template<class T>
    utility::string_t parameterToString(const boost::optional<T>& value);

    template<class T>
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<T>& value);

// [...]
};

template<class T>
utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::vector<T>& value)
{
    utility::stringstream_t ss;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < value.size(); i++)
    {
        if( i > 0) ss << utility::conversions::to_string_t(", ");
        ss << ApiClient::parameterToString(value[i]);
    }

    return ss.str();
}

template<class T>
utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const boost::optional<T>& value)
{
    if (value.has_value()) {
        return parameterToString(*value.get());
    }
    else {
        return "** nullptr (A) **";
    }
}

template<class T>
utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const boost::optional<const std::shared_ptr<T>>& value)
{
    if (value.has_value()) {
        return parameterToString(*value.get());
    }
    else {
        return "** nullptr (B) **";
    }
}

template<class T>
utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<T>& value)
{
    return parameterToString(*value.get());
}
}

And its attempt to be used fails here, for example:
pplx::task<std::shared_ptr<VideoChapters>> VideoChaptersApi::getVideoChapters(
   std::shared_ptr<_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter> id, 
   boost::optional<utility::string_t> xPeertubeVideoPassword) const
{
    // [...]

    boost::replace_all(localVarPath, 
      utility::conversions::to_string_t("{") + utility::conversions::to_string_t("id") + 
      utility::conversions::to_string_t("}"), 
      web::uri::encode_uri(ApiClient::parameterToString(id)));

    // [...]
}

where _api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter is a class that has nothing special. it fails with the messages:
ApiClient.h: In instantiation of 
‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&) 
[with T = org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter; utility::string_t = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
LiveVideosApi.cpp:245:210:   required from here

ApiClient.h:105:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type&)’
  105 |     return parameterToString(*value.get());
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:89:19: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::vector<_Type>&)’
   89 | utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::vector<T>& value)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:89:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ApiClient.h:105:29: note:   ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} is not derived from ‘const std::vector<_Type>’
  105 |     return parameterToString(*value.get());
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:103:19: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&)’
  103 | utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<T>& value)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:103:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ApiClient.h:105:29: note:   ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} is not derived from ‘const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>’
  105 |     return parameterToString(*value.get());
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:59:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(utility::string_t)’
   59 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(utility::string_t value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:59:66: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘utility::string_t’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
   59 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(utility::string_t value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:60:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(int32_t)’
   60 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(int32_t value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:60:56: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’}
   60 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(int32_t value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:61:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(int64_t)’
   61 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(int64_t value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:61:56: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘int64_t’ {aka ‘long int’}
   61 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(int64_t value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:62:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(float)’
   62 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(float value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:62:54: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘float’
   62 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(float value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:63:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(double)’
   63 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(double value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ApiClient.h:63:55: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘double’
   63 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(double value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:64:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(const utility::datetime&)’
   64 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(const utility::datetime &value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:64:73: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘const utility::datetime&’
   64 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(const utility::datetime &value);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

ApiClient.h:65:30: note: candidate: ‘static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(bool)’
   65 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(bool value);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:65:53: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} to ‘bool’
   65 |     static utility::string_t parameterToString(bool value);
      |                                                ~~~~~^~~~~

I don't understand how to handle this refusal:
ApiClient.h:103:19: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> static utility::string_t org::openapitools::client::api::ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&)’
  103 | utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const std::shared_ptr<T>& value)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
ApiClient.h:103:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ApiClient.h:105:29: note:   ‘std::__shared_ptr<org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::element_type’ {aka ‘org::openapitools::client::model::_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter’} is not derived from ‘const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>’
  105 |     return parameterToString(*value.get());
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

According to the message I'm reading, I should have an additional prototype available?
template<class T>
static utility::string_t parameterToString(const T& value);

?
But it looks to me dangerous to declare such one, as some cases, like boost::optional<...> parameters requires a special handling (just started here):
template<class T>
utility::string_t ApiClient::parameterToString(const boost::optional<const std::shared_ptr<T>>& value)
{
    if (value.has_value()) {
        return parameterToString(*value.get());
    }
    else {
        return "** nullptr (B) **";
    }
}

So, I don't think it could/should be summarized in a "T& only" method.
How should I correct the template defined in ApiClient.h so that parameters of kind const std::shared_ptr<T>& value or const boost::optional<const std::shared_ptr<T>>& value will be accepted?
Thanks!

You'll need a new overload taking a _api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter, I don't see how you'd implement a template taking any type even if that wouldn't cause other problems

@AlanBirtles is right, looks like the generated code handles the optional/vectors/shared_ptrs but it's your responsibility to handle the classes stored in those containers.

You should add an overload like this one inside the ApiClient class and take care of it ignoring optionals/vectors/shared_ptrs/etc:
    static utility::string_t parameterToString(int32_t value);

For example:
class  ApiClient
{
public:
// [...]
    static utility::string_t
        parameterToString(_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_parameter const& value)
    {
        return value.to_string(); 
    }

};

What is weird, is that approach does not meet the open-closed principle. Usually you implement this kind of function inside your namespace/class:
struct _api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_param {
  friend utility::string_t
    parameterToString(_api_v1_videos_ownership__id__accept_post_id_param const& );
};

That would work if instead of class ApiClient they declare namespace ApiClient.

Thanks! I've not replied yet, because I'm attempting what you are suggesting. OpenApi generator works well, but sometimes the way it does things is strange, this is why I'm looking from S.O. support. I'm trying to add the enum handlings feature that is missing in C++ RestSDK. Here, what we are in front of, I think, is a yaml Open Api file that uses classes for input parameters, in some methods, instead of the usual int, string... This is why the generator is tricked, I think.

The yaml Open Api I took for generating attempt. It is large and complex enough to be a challenge, and if I can make OpenApi generator generating from it, I'll be happy.
